# Is it secure to send authentication token in HTTP/S response body?

Tags: rest, api, security, http, token

In order to put some additional Information about the access- and refresh-token in a REST API response, I thought about creating a token object, that carries all the information which I want to append to the token and send it along with the usual JSON response.

Would this be less secure? If yes, why and how could I work around the security leak?

Comment: Why would the access token be in a response?

Comment: Maybe his api requires that the client should first obtain an access token and then use it for the api call

Comment: Yes Nadir Latif is right, to access secure information the client requires an access token. This token is provided by the API, as soon as the client logs in with his user credentials. I thought this is the standard procedure for APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Well its possible to decrypt SSL traffic using Wireshark. You should encrypt your access token before sending it to the client in api response

Comment: The access token encrypts a user object, which holds all information about the user, that needs the API to do its backend stuff.
I use this module [link](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) to create and read out the token.

Comment: Does your answer also handle the problem of "Man in the Middle" attacks?

Comment: Well Wireshark allows sniffing traffic so it can be used to decrypt https traffic and perform man in the middle attacks. For example a user can decrypt your https traffic and find out how to use your access token. You should keep a time limit on your access token so it can only be used for certain duration